# remote firewall configuration on centos7

Tags: firewall, centos7

I'm using Centos 7 and am trying to configure my firewall remotely. When I run `firewall-config &` a window comes up but remains blank. I cannot kill the window with the X close button so I need to kill -9 the process.

Any ideas why this would be blank?

Am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried **yum install firewall-config** you may be missing dependencies.

Also have a look at this:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-Using_Firewalls.html

Comment: yum install firewall-config says nothing to do.

I had looked at the link you posted, and it assumes I'm at a gui. I am trying to run this from SSL using xwindows

Comment: Most of that document is running commands from the CLI.  There are only a few parts that involve the GUI.  Sorry if this didn't help, but I got this working out of the box on a minimal install using that guide.

Comment: Yes, CLI might be the only option. I was hoping to be able to launch firewall-config through X as a GUI, though. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't get this to work, but it turns out the cli isn't very difficult to use. Thanks.

Comment: Lol guess you can't undo the -1?

Comment: I didn't put it in -- I don't have enough reputation to change it

Comment: Oh no problem, I was only joking :)